# How can I perform a composition of Mats with emgu (c#)?

Tags: c#, emgucv

i am trying to rotate and shift a mat at the same time. 
My first matrix comes from the following instruction:

CvInvoke.GetRotationMatrix2D(new Point(0, 0), ia.getAngle(), 1.0, rotation);

My second matric comes from the following instructions:

```
 Mat translation = CvInvoke.GetAffineTransform(t1, t2);
```

where t1 and t2 are vertices of two triangles
I do not want tu use Matrix. I want to perform the operation with Mat.

How can I multiply these two matrices in order to get the final one that I will use to apply the **CvInvoke.WarpAffine** method.

I tried: 
`cvInvoke.Multiply`, 
it does not transform the image.
I am currently trying
 `CvInvoke.Gemm(rotation, translation, 1.0, null, 0.0, final);` 
but an exception occurs:

> (An unhandled exception of type 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred
>   in Emgu.CV.World.dll Additional information: OpenCV: a_size.width ==
>   len)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. When a translation is in play, matrices have to be of size 3x3. So I modified my code and used the following methods:
    CvInvoke.FindHomography(t1, t2, H);
    CvInvoke.WarpPerspective(img, big_img, H, ROIRotatedArea.Size);
where t1 are the points of the source image and t2 are the corresponding points of the transformed image and H is the transformation matrix. t1, t2 and H are of Matrix type.

Hope it will help someone someday.